# How to use the serial port in an unrooted Android device using pyserial?

Tags: android, pyserial, usb-otg, qpython

I am using a Nexus 7 with latest vanilla Android build and would like to use QPython with pyserial to get to a Prolific usb-serial port via a OTG cable.

I can confirm that the driver exists on the tablet at `/sys/bus/usbserial/drivers` and that the device shows up as `/sys/bus/devices/ttyUSB0` folder.  I can also use other apps with the serial port.

I do not have permissions to `/dev/ttyUSB0` so how do I set `Serial.port` to open it successfully without rooting the device?  Is there a different device file I can use in the `/sys` folder structure or some other folder?

Is there a native USB library available so that I can use so that I can use pyserial via PyUSB?

Is there a `.jar` file I can wrap so that I can call the serial port from Python?

Any other suggestions in getting the serial port working from Python?